# Get RowId from QueryChangeDescription

Tags: java, oracle

To my Oracle Database I have registered a `DatabaseChangeNotification` with a SQL-Query. I like to get any changes on the defined `TABLE`.

```
DatabaseChangeRegistration changeRegistration;

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS, "true");
properties.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_QUERY_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION, "true")

changeRegistration = connection.registerDatabaseChangeNotification(properties);

DCNListener dcnListener = new DCNListener(this);
changeRegistration.addListener(this);

Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
((OracleStatement) statement).setDatabaseChangeRegistration(changeRegistration);
String sql = "SELECT * from TABLE";

statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

In my Listener I receive the `DatabaseChangeEvents`

```
public void onDatabaseChangeNotification(DatabaseChangeEvent databaseChangeEvent) {
  TableChangeDescription[] tableChangeDescription = databaseChangeEvent.getTableChangeDescription();
  QueryChangeDescription[] queryChangeDescription = databaseChangeEvent.getQueryChangeDescription();
  for (QueryChangeDescription qcd: queryChangeDescription) {
    String result = qcd.toString();
    System.out.println(qcd);
  }
}
```

1. `tabelChangeDescription` is null
2. My result is:

> query ID=201, query change event type=QUERYCHANGE
>        Table Change Description (length=1):    operation=[UPDATE], tableName=USER.TABLE, objectNumber=67385
>       Row Change Description (length=1):
>         ROW:  operation=UPDATE, ROWID=AAAQc5AAHAAAAG/AAB

Is there any nice way to get the ROWID from the Changes row else than String-Parsing? I can't find any `getRowId`-Method on the `QueryChangeDescription`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the was to get the RowId. From the `queryChangeDescription` you can get the `TabeleChangeDesciptions` which has nothing in Common with the TableChangeDecription from the event. If there are changes on more than one Table, these tables where listed in the Array.
Because I am registered to only one Table I don't have to iterate over the list.

After habing the the `TableChangeDescription`you can get the `RowChangeDescription` for each changed row. From this you can get the RowId.

```
for (QueryChangeDescription queryChangeDescription : databaseChangeEvent.getQueryChangeDescription()) {
  RowChangeDescription[] rowChangeDescriptions = queryChangeDescription.getTableChangeDescription()[0].getRowChangeDescription();
  for (RowChangeDescription rowChangeDescription : rowChangeDescriptions) {
    handleEvent(rowChangeDescription.getRowid());
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue and I followed your answer but I am getting error at `queryChangeDescription.getTableChangeDescription()[0]` It is not able to find method `getTableChangeDescription()` Please help!

Comment: @kittu do you have the 'oracle.jdbc.dcn.QueryChangeDescription'? I updated my answer with my whole snippet.